# SSRS Multi-series Chart

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a requirement as below.
I need to show the number of clients in a chart based on their income and age group.

X-axis -> <10k <20k <50k <100k <200k+

Y-axis -> Age Group(20-30, 31-40, 41-50, 51+

The chart should show count of clients who falls on income and age range. For example, there will be 20 clients in the age group 20-30 with an income < 10k and 30 clients with an income less than 100k. then I have to show 20 on a bar chart under 20-30 Age group and <10k range.

Is this achievable in chart in SSRS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YES - it is possible.

In the chart group by, you would need to use an **Expression** to achieve your income and age groups.

```
=IIF(FIELDS!AGE.VALUE < 20 THEN "<20", 
 IIF(FIELDS!AGE.VALUE < 30 THEN "20-30", 
 IIF(FIELDS!AGE.VALUE < 41 THEN "31-40", 
 IIF(FIELDS!AGE.VALUE < 51 THEN "41-50", 
 "51+"))))
```

and then a similar one for your income axis:

```
=IIF(FIELDS!INCOME.VALUE < 10000 THEN "<10K", 
 IIF(FIELDS!INCOME.VALUE < 20000 THEN "<20K", 
 IIF(FIELDS!INCOME.VALUE < 50000 THEN "<50K", 
 IIF(FIELDS!INCOME.VALUE < 100000 THEN "<100K", 
 "<200K"))))
```

Now that I look at it, your last range is actually 100,000k+

What kind of chart are you making? The Y axis would usually contain the count of clients for each group.

**UPDATE:**
For a bar chart, you would use the series to create a separate bar for each Age group in the Income group like this:
[image]
Imagine the **Double-Precision** category as your **Income** group and the type category (Atom, Athlon, Xeon) as your **Age**.

Comment: Thank you very much for quick reply. My requirement is to show Age Group values (20-30, 31-40, 41-50, 51+) on Y- axis and Income values (<10k <20k <50k <100k <200k+) on X-axis. And the count on Bar chart(count of clients) or any other type of chart should indicate the count that satisfies corresponding values in X-axis and Y-axis values. For example, a count 20 in the above question will show under 20-30 Age Group(Y-axis) and (<10k) on X-axis. Is this kind of chart achievable. It's like like 3D chart.

Comment: @sarayucm - A bar chart would have your categories along the X-Axis and the values along the Y-axis. Normally they would have a series of Age bars for each Income bracket.

I think you would need to do something like a bubble chart for what you are sayng with your Income categories across the X and Age Groups on the Y axis. The bubble **size** would represent the count of clients who are in the two categories.